# Laravel 5.2 Modify Request After Form Validation Before Controller

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm using laravel 5.2 and i'm using Form Request that given by laravel vendor to make my code clean, so i don't have many code on my controller :

```
public function store( CouponRequest $request )
{
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $coupon = Coupon::create( $request->all() );

        DB::commit();
        return redirect()->route('admin.coupons.index');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();
        return redirect()->back()->withInput();
    }
```

And this is my sample code about my request form :

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ( strtolower( $this->method ) ) {
        case 'post':
        {
            return [
                'code' => 'required|unique:coupons,code',
                'name' => 'required',
                'start_year' => 'required',
                'start_month' => 'required',
                'start_day' => 'required',
                'start_time' => 'required',
                'finish_year' => 'required',
                'finish_month' => 'required',
                'finish_day' => 'required',
                'finish_time' => 'required',
                'using_time' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required',
                'free_shipment' => 'required',
                'target' => 'required',
                'target_user' => 'required'
            ];
        }
        case 'put':
        {
            return [
                'code' => 'required',
                'name' => 'required',
                'start_year' => 'required',
                'start_month' => 'required',
                'start_day' => 'required',
                'start_time' => 'required',
                'finish_year' => 'required',
                'finish_month' => 'required',
                'finish_day' => 'required',
                'finish_time' => 'required',
                'using_time' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required',
                'free_shipment' => 'required',
                'target' => 'required',
                'target_user' => 'required'
            ];
        }
        default:
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
}
```

Where should i place this command? :

```
$start_date = Carbon::create( $request->start_year, $request->start_month, $request->start_day );
$start_date->setTimeFromTimeString( $request->start_time );
$finish_date = Carbon::create( $request->finish_year, $request->finish_month, $request->finish_day );
$finish_date->setTimeFromTimeString( $request->finish_time );
```

If i place this code before validation, i could be error when some field not filled well by users.

So what i want is to place this code after validation success, but i don't want to place it at my controller.

Is there FormRequest function that can be called after validation success to modify my request??

I think it's not good when there's much code at controller, so i want to minimalize my controller code.

Comment: you can use a middleware

Comment: the work flow will like this : middleware -> form request -> controller right? so if i place my code at middleware, it will not validate

Comment: Don't do that. Middleware provide a mechanism for filtering HTTP requests entering your application. Not transforming http requests. You will end up with a confusing code base. You can write a service instead. That will also make your controller much more cleaner and SOLID.

Comment: Who is using the `$start_date` and `$finish_date`? Are you persisting it or using it?

Comment: @HilmiErdemKEREN has right, I probably misunderstood your question. You can create a service and inject it to controller. Service container will take care for the wirring

Answer (score 1):

I am going to attempt this using FormRequest. If the intention here is to both ***validate*** and **assign** start_date and finish_date, this is probably the plausible way of doing so in Laravel:

```
public function rules()
{
    switch ( strtolower( $this->method ) ) {
        case 'post':
        {
            return [
                'code' => 'required|unique:coupons,code',
                'name' => 'required',
                'start_year' => 'required',
                'start_month' => 'required',
                'start_day' => 'required',
                'start_time' => 'required',
                'finish_year' => 'required',
                'finish_month' => 'required',
                'finish_day' => 'required',
                'finish_time' => 'required',
                'using_time' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required',
                'free_shipment' => 'required',
                'target' => 'required',
                'target_user' => 'required'
            ];
        }
        case 'put':
        {
            return [
                'code' => 'required',
                'name' => 'required',
                'start_year' => 'required',
                'start_month' => 'required',
                'start_day' => 'required',
                'start_time' => 'required',
                'finish_year' => 'required',
                'finish_month' => 'required',
                'finish_day' => 'required',
                'finish_time' => 'required',
                'using_time' => 'required',
                'type' => 'required',
                'free_shipment' => 'required',
                'target' => 'required',
                'target_user' => 'required'
            ];
        }
        default:
        {
            return [];
        }
    }
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 *
 * This method overrides Laravel's defeault FormRequest
 * to create validator with `after()` hook
 */
protected function validator($validator)
{
    $validator
        ->make(
            $this->validationData(), $this->rules(), $this->messages(), $this->attributes()
        )
        ->after(function($validator) {

            if ($date = $this->getCarbonInstanceFromPrefix('start')) {
                $request->start_date = $date;
            } else {
                $validator->errors()
                    ->add('start_year', 'Invalid starting date and time');
            }

            if ($date = $this->getCarbonInstanceFromPrefix('finish')) {
                $request->finish_year = $date;
            } else {
                $validator->errors()
                    ->add('finish_year', 'Invalid finish date and time');
            }

        });
}

/**
 * Retrieve carbon instance from current request, using prefix
 *
 * @param  string $prefix
 *
 * @return Carbon|null
 */
protected function getCarbonInstanceFromPrefix($prefix = '')
{
    try {
        $date = Carbon::create( 
            $request->get($prefix . '_year'), 
            $request->get($prefix . '_month'), 
            $request->get($prefix . '_day') 
        );
        $date->setTimeFromTimeString( $request->get($prefix . '_time') );
        return $date;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Quick Explanation

FormRequest essentially extends from `Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest` and can override the method where instance of `Validator` is created. By creating your custom validator, you can attach `after()` event to both validate each date inputs, and also assign additional parameter to request in one go.